# Estimating the variance of eigenvalues of sample covariance matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, covariance, variance, eigenvalue

I am trying to investigate the statistical variance of the eigenvalues of sample covariance matrices using Matlab. To clarify, each **sample** covariance matrix is constructed from a **finite** number of vector snapshots (afflicted with random white Gaussian noise). Then, over a **large** number of trials, a large number of such matrices are generated and eigendecomposed in order to estimate the **theoretical** statistics of the eigenvalues.

According to several sources (see, for example, [1, Eq.3] and [2, Eq.11]), the variance of each **sample** eigenvalue should be equal to that **theoretical** eigenvalue squared, divided by the number of vector snapshots used for each covariance matrix. However, the results I get from Matlab aren't even close.

Is this an issue with my code? With Matlab? (I've never had such trouble working on similar problems).

Here's a very simple example:

```
% Data vector length
Lvec = 5;
% Number of snapshots per sample covariance matrix
N = 200;
% Number of simulation trials
Ntrials = 10000;
% Noise variance
sigma2 = 10;

% Theoretical covariance matrix
Rnn_th = sigma2*eye(Lvec);
% Theoretical eigenvalues (should all be sigma2)
lambda_th = sort(eig(Rnn_th),'descend');

lambda = zeros(Lvec,Ntrials);
for trial = 1:Ntrials
    % Generate new (complex) white Gaussian noise data
    n = sqrt(sigma2/2)*(randn(Lvec,N) + 1j*randn(Lvec,N));
    % Sample covariance matrix
    Rnn = n*n'/N;
    % Save sample eigenvalues
    lambda(:,trial) = sort(eig(Rnn),'descend');   
end

% Estimated eigenvalue covariance matrix
b = lambda - lambda_th(:,ones(1,Ntrials));
Rbb = b*b'/Ntrials
% Predicted (approximate) theoretical result
Rbb_th_approx = diag(lambda_th.^2/N)
```

References:

[1] Friedlander, B.; Weiss, A.J.; , "[On the second-order statistics of the eigenvectors of sample covariance matrices](http://www.scribd.com/doc/112067632)," Signal Processing, IEEE Transactions on , vol.46, no.11, pp.3136-3139, Nov 1998
[2] Kaveh, M.; Barabell, A.; , "[The statistical performance of the MUSIC and the minimum-norm algorithms in resolving plane waves in noise](http://www.scribd.com/doc/112046406/Kaveh-86)," Acoustics, Speech and Signal Processing, IEEE Transactions on , vol.34, no.2, pp. 331- 341, Apr 1986

Comment: Where do you actually compute the variance of the estimated eigenvalues? `b = lambda - lambda_th(:,ones(1,Ntrials)); Rbb = b*b'/Ntrials` doesn't do that, it computes the variance–covariance-matrix of the difference between estimates and theoretical values.

Answer (score 0):

According to the abstract of from your first reference:

"Formulas for the second-order statistics of the eigenvectors have been derived in the statistical literature and are widely used. We point out a discrepancy between the statistics observed in numerical simulations and the theoretical formulas, due to the nonuniqueness of the definition of eigenvectors. We present two ways to resolve this discrepancy. The first involves modifying the theoretical formulas to match the computational results. The second involved a simple modification of the computations to make them match existing formulas."

Sounds like there is a discrepancy, and it also sounds like the two 'solutions' are hacks, but without access to the actual paper, it's kind of hard to help.

Comment: That refers to the eigenvectors (which are a little tricky because they are non-unique). However, I'm only looking at the eigenvalues, for which there is no discrepancy.

I'll attempt to edit the original post so the references are links to the papers.